# Is it possible to await for an async-enumerable in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need to write a method that returns an IEnumerable of objects in an async-fashion and a Foreach loop that goes through the returned IEnumerable of objects from that method.
I'm using .Net Core 2 and not quite sure how to approach this task.
Is it possible in .netcore2 to return an async IEnumerable?

```
public async IEnumerable<int> MethodThatReturnsObjectsAsync()
{
}

foreach(int item in await MethodThatReturnsObjectsAsync())
{
    Action(item);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its fine, it only gets called once. It only creates one state machine (If your calling method is an `async` method.. i.e `async Task`, `async Task<T>`, `Async void`)

In your case

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Test(Action<something> action)
{
   foreach (int item in await MethodThatReturnsObjectsAsync())
   {
      action(item);
   }

   ...

   return ...
}
private static async Task<IEnumerable<int>> MethodThatReturnsObjectsAsync()
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Nope, only if the return type would be Task<IEnumerable<int>>

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately it is not possible at the moment. .NET Core 3.0 will ship with an `IAsyncEnumerable` which can do that, but that's a preview for now.

Comment: This is not one of the features tied to the .NET Core 3.0 runtime. It will run older on .NET Framework and .NET Core runtimes.